# SOAP faultcode env:Client using SOAPClientSaaj

Tags: java, xml, soap, soapui

I have an xml which when hit at a region(URL) i am getting the below XML as response , can please anyone suggest why is this happening , 
If i execute the same xml manually using SOAPUI , it executes fine, throws error with my Java code.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
  <soapenv:Fault xmlns:en="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <faultcode>en:Client</faultcode>
     <faultstring>The service provider does not support requested service</faultstring>
  </soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

my java code is :-

```
public class SOAPClientSAAJ {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws SOAPException, IOException {

    // Create SOAP Connection
    SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory
            .newInstance();
    SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory
            .createConnection();

    // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
    String url = "SOME URL";
    SOAPMessage soapRq = readSoapMessage("C:\\1.1.1.xml");
    SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapRq, url);

    // print SOAP Response
    System.out.print("Response SOAP Message:" + "\n");
    soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);

    soapConnection.close();
}

public static SOAPMessage readSoapMessage(String filename)
        throws SOAPException, FileNotFoundException {
    SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
    soapPart.setContent(new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(filename)));
    message.saveChanges();
    return message;
}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: It is difficult to say without seeing the request. I would suggest to validate the content of the xml in soapUI and see.

Comment: Can you also show the raw request from SoapUI as you say it successfully worked?